# Pass data from one it block to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

[image]

As you can see in the above image, controller value assigned in first it block is not the same anymore in second it block. Is this the default behavior? Can we do some changes in karma config file to get rid of this issue?

This project is based on angularjs 1.7.9 which is using karma and jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take advantage of `beforeEach`.

```
describe('Login', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    $controller.name = 'Pankaj';
  });

  it('test one', function () {
    console.log($controller.name);
  });
   
  it('test two', function () {
    console.log($controller.name);
  });
});
```

`beforeEach` runs before every `it` block.

Edit

You have to use `describe, beforeEach, beforeAll, afterEach, and afterAll` appropriately. `describe` you can split by features/situations, `beforeEach` runs before every `it`, `beforeAll` runs once in a `describe` block, `afterEach` runs after each `it` in a `describe` block, and `afterAll` runs once after all the `it` blocks completed in a `desribe` block.

```
describe('Login', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    $controller.name = 'Pankaj';
  });

  it('test one', function () {
    console.log($controller.name);
  });

  it('test two', function () {
    console.log($controller.name);
  });
  describe('dynamic part', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // call the function that will change the variable
    });
    it('test 1', function () {
      // your assertions
    });
    it('test 2', function () {
      // your assertions
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What about dynamic part of code? what if I call a function from first block which initializing some variable and then have to use the same variable in second block?

Comment: But putting that function call in beforeEach will increase the load of unit testing. Isn't there any other way around?

Comment: I think it will be minimal. I can't think of another way.